# Vuejs2: how to judge props update when using object as a prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose I have an array `feedsArray`, the example value may look like this:

```
this.feedsArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'Comment',
    value: 'How are you today ?'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'Meet',
    name: 'Daily sync up'
  }
]
```

Suppose I have registered two components: `Comment` and `Meet`, Each component has a prop setting as the following:

```
props: {
  feed: Object
}
```

and the main component has the following definition:

```
<component v-for="feed in feedsArray" :feed="feed" :key="feed.id" :is="feed.type"></component>
```

As you can see, it uses `is` property to select different component. My question is, how to detect feed object change in the child component ? Like when I set

```
this.feedsArray[0] = {
  id: 1,
  type: 'Comment',
  value: 'I am not ok'
}
```

How can the `Comment` component detect the changes ? I tried to add a watcher definition in the child component like the following:

```
watch: {
  feed: {
    handler (val) {
      console.log('this feed is changed')
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
```

But it doesn't work here. Anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: Because you're assigning the same `id` (and which you use in `:key="feed.id"`), I have a feeling Vue's reactivity won't kick in as it won't re-render the `v-for` components

Comment: You got the key ! But in this way the component will destroy first and later will render again, I wonder is there anyway can only update the component but not re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not assign directly to an array using index - use `splice()` instead, otherwise JavaScript can not detect that you have changed the array.

If you want to change only the value of an already existing key of an object - then simply update it e.g. `this.feeds[0].value = 'I am not okay any more';`

This works for existing keys only - otherwise you have to use `this.$set(this.feeds[0], 'value', 'I am not okay any more');`